# Hide Gridview Row when Button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When the page loads there is a gridview on the screen with an asp button below it.  What I want to do is when the user clicks the button it hides a row on the gridview.  I don't want the data deleted out of the datasource I simply want to hide it from the user. Any idea how to do this in C#

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReceive" runat="server" Height="156px" Text="Receive" 
        Width="131px" onclick="btnReceive_Click" />



    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Aitem" HeaderText="A" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Bitem" HeaderText="B" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using javascript?

Comment: No. No idea how to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested This solution, But I think the way is Css, this will put visible false the `count() - 1`:

Put a update panel in your grid

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>   
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "ProductName" HeaderText="A" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "CategoryName" HeaderText="B" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

//Put this when you populate the grid
ViewState["X"] = GridView1.Rows.Count;
ViewState["Y"] = 1;
```

An in your button put this:

```
    protected void btnReceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int X = int.Parse(ViewState["X"].ToString());
            int Y = int.Parse(ViewState["Y"].ToString());
            if (Y < GridView1.Rows.Count )
            {
                GridView1.Rows[X - Y].Visible = false;
                ViewState["Y"] = Y + 1; 
            }
    }
```

If you need to show the rows again only create another method with  `gvrow.Visible = true;`

I don't know if this is the best way but works.
I hope that help.

Comment: I have a timer in my update panel since a new row comes in the gridview it has to be updated every so often. When the timer refreshes the update panel it refreshes the gridview and it brings back the row that was hidden. Anyway to get around this.

Comment: @Apollo But only I put the update panel in the example but you could remove it.

Comment: I already had the Update panel in place. Is needed since I have to show the records that come in regularly and when a button is clicked it gets the next record and it hides that record from gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

gridview Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                Text="Click1" 
                OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton) sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
clickedRow.Visible = false;
  }
```

Comment: The button is not in the gridview, is outside the gridview.